# How can I reach sender at numberOfRowInSection function?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make expandable tableview cell with header. I have model for my datas. I add isExpanded variable bool for decided situation of cell so in numberOfRowsInSection function gave me Index error. I have logic which have isExpanded variable but its not working correctly. How can I fix it? Here my code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        if self.userAdressDict[0].isExpanded == true {
            return 0
        }
        if self.userAdressDict[0].isExpanded == false {
            return self.userAdressDict.count
        }
    }
    if section == 1 {
        return self.userAdressDictForTeslim.count

    }
    return 1
}
```

Here my header view code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Kapat", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleExpandCloseForAlim(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }
    if section == 1 {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Kapat", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleExpandCloseForTeslim), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }
    else{
        return nil
    }
}
```

And here button action function:

```
@objc func handleExpandCloseForAlim(sender: UIButton) {
    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
    for row in self.userAdressDict.indices{
        print(0 , row)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
        indexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: (sender.tag), section: 0)
    let adresso = self.userAdressDict[indexPath.row]
    if adresso.isExpanded == true {
        tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths , with: .fade)
    }
    if adresso.isExpanded == false {
        tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    }
    //self.userAdressDict.removeAll()

}
```

I can make delete process with removeAll() code. But I want to insert rows also so this way not correct way to do that. (userAdressDict is my model which hold datas). In handleExpandCloseForAlim function's sender for reach isExpanded variable. I have problem about numberOfRowsInSection part lastly.

Comment: what is crash reason printed there.

Comment: @PravinTate _Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range_ is error code in `if self.userAdressDict[0].isExpanded == true {`

Comment: Did you fix that issue with the data loading that you asked about the other day (and then deleted the question)? Is this a similar crash?

Comment: @Koen I did it correctly after 4 hour working thank you for your interest but its not a similar crash as you can see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use guard to see if there are any elements in your array, some thing like this:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        guard let element = self.userAdressDict.first as? AdresStruct else { return 0 }

        if element.isExpanded {
            return 0
        }
        else {
            return self.userAdressDict.count
        }
    }

    if section == 1 {
        return self.userAdressDictForTeslim.count
    }

    return 1
}
```

Comment: You said the error is in `numberOfRowsInSection `, on what line exactly? You need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: For your answer it gave in `guard let element = self.userAdressDict[0] as? adresStruct else { return 1 }`

Comment: Try `self.userAdressDict.first` instead of `self.userAdressDict[0]`

Comment: Its gave same error at cellForRowAt indexPath function. In `let adresGelen = self.userAdressDict[indexPath.item]` code.

Comment: So the error in `numberOfRowsInSection` is gone? If this solved your question, please mark the answer as accepted. For your crash in `cellForRowAt`, try a similar `guard` syntax. Or create a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it broke a code that's already running. So this isn't actually the answer I'm looking for. It just broke a different place. Means nurberOfRowsInSection function didn't working yet.

Comment: Try `else { return 0 }` instead of `else { return 1 }`.

Comment: Hey Koen me again. Its working when I try it in section zero but when I try to make it avaible for section one too its crash again. Its gave index error again but I made exactly same thing for first time. What do you think about that?

Comment: I recommend you make a new question. Please include only the relevant code and make sure you say exactly on what line you get the crash.

Answer (score 0):

change these lines

```
if self.userAdressDict[0].isExpanded == false {
            return self.userAdressDict.count
        }
    }
    if section == 1 {
        return self.userAdressDictForTeslim.count

    }
```

to

```
if self.userAdressDict[0].isExpanded == false {
            return self.userAdressDict.count - 1
        }
    }
    if section == 1 {
        return self.userAdressDictForTeslim.count - 1

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I got wrong can you try with adresso variable with getting indexPath.row - 1

Comment: `let adresso = self.userAdressDict[indexPath.row] - 1 ` when I tried that gives that error _ Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'adresStruct' and 'Int'_

Comment: [indexPath.row - 1 ] if this won’t work I will look at problem in my laptop

Comment: I tried that now [indexPath.row - 1 ] in adresso but its give same error.

Comment: I will be around